# How to create a custom dataproc image based on a preview release

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I was trying to create a custom Dataproc image in GCP. It works fine with a base image that is in stable release (for example 1.3.24). However, if I specify a base image that is in preview (for example 1.4.0), I receive the following error messages:

if I specify one of the following as `--dataproc-version`,

- `1.4.0-deb9`
- `1.4.0`
- `1.4`

I get `RuntimeError: ('Cannot find dataproc base image with dataproc-version=%s.', '<the specified version>')`

if I specify one of the following as `--dataproc-version`

- `1.4.0-RC8`
- `1.4.0-RC8-deb9`

I get `generate_custom_image.py: error: argument --dataproc-version: Invalid version: <the specified version>.`

Therefore the question is, can we build a custom Dataproc image based on  a preview release? If so how should I specify the `--dataproc-version`?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the CLI I get the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Failed to
>   resolve image version '1.4'. Accepted image versions: [0.1, 0.2, 1.0,
>   1.0-deb9, 1.1, 1.1-deb9, 1.2, 1.2-deb9, 1.3, 1.3-deb9, preview]. See https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-versions
>   for additional information on image versioning.

So, if I use `preview` it works and creates one with `1.4.0-RC10-deb9`:

```sh
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name --image-version preview
```

EDIT: regarding custom images

After inspecting what the script does it retrieves theimages using [this filter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/blob/master/custom-images/generate_custom_image.py#L124). If we just list all of them we can see the available ones such as:

```sh
$ gcloud compute images list --project cloud-dataproc
...
dataproc-1-4-deb9-20190213-000000-rc01                cloud-dataproc                                                   READY
```

One possible way to select that one would be to replace lines 122-123 of `generate_custom_image.py` with:

```
filter_arg = "--filter=name:dataproc-1-4-deb9-20190213-000000-rc01"
```

and call the script with a dummy version for the regex:

```sh
python generate_custom_image.py --dataproc-version 1.2.0 ...
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. It is not the creation of the cluster that is troubling me, it is the creation of the VM that the cluster is based on. i.e. this process https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dataproc-images. However, it's still great that now I know I can try out `preview` as a version. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it seems it is not straightforward in that case and the script needs to be modified. I have edited my answer, let me know if that works

Comment: thank you for the help and tips. I tried `dataproc-1-4-deb9-20190213-000000-rc01` and the process completed without problem. However, unfortunately, the content of the image is not as advertised. I am not able to find python 3.7 (Seems that none of the rc01, rc02 or rc03 have it).

Answer (score 3):

According to the source code of [generate_custom_image.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-dataproc/blob/master/custom-images/generate_custom_image.py)

```
47 # Old style images: 1.2.3
48 # New style images: 1.2.3-deb8
49 _VERSION_REGEX = re.compile(r"^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(-.{4})?$")
```

Only 1.4.0-deb9 can match the regex but 1.4.0-RC10-deb9 will not match.

If you want to use preview release, you need to change the regex in generate_custom_image.py

Update: I have sent pull request to dataproc cumstom image

Comment: Thank you so much! Having the image tags working would be very convenient in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reporting and fixing this! Note, that python version was changed from 3.7 to 3.6 in the latest image release according to [this](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.4).